# Переход на другую страницу сайта .html на языке PHP

Tags: php

```
if ($mail == 1) {}
```

Есть почтовый скрипт, надо, чтобы по его завершению, если письмо отправляется, открывалась другая страница сайта.

То есть, после отправки письма из формы на `index.htm` был переход автоматический на `reviews.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($mail == 1) {
    header("Location: /reviews.html");
}
```

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что до использования команды header в браузер ничего не должно выводиться, т.е либо использовать вместе с ob_start()